# Instantiate generic class that implements generic interface

Tags: java, android

I have encountered a series of problems when instantiate generic class that implements generic interface:
I have an generic interface IA

```
interface IA<MyClass, String>
```

I have a generic class that implements this interface

```
class ClassA implements IA<MyClass, String> {
    // constructor
    public ClassA(boolean someParam){
    }
    String func(){
        return "abc"; 
    }
}
```

First issue I have is when I instantiate object of ClassA

```
IA<MyClass,String> objectA = new ClassA(false);
```

I got the warning that use <>  for Generic type. So I added that

```
IA<MyClass,String> objectA = new ClassA<>(false);
```

Then I got compile error: cannot infer type arguments for ClassA.
After a few search on web, I found I may need to specify type argument in definition, so I change the class definition to

```
class ClassA<MyClass, String> implements IA<MyClass, String> {
    // constructor
    public ClassA(boolean someParam){
    }
    String func(){
        return "abc"; 
    }
}
```

Now I fixed that, but got other error on func() saying the "require String, found java.lang.String".

One of the posts suggested that compiler confused any "String" in the class with generic type argument String and should remove it from type argument. So I changed to the following:

```
class ClassA<MyClass> implements IA<MyClass, String> {
    // constructor
    public ClassA(boolean someParam){
    }
    String func(){
        return "abc"; 
    }
    void func2(){
        MyClassObj.someFunctionCall();//MyClassObj is an instance of MyClasss
    }
}
```

Then the change above breaks MyClassObj.someFunctionCall(). Compiler says someFunctionCall() is not recognized.

Most of the code exists in codebase already and I'm just modifying some logic. Are those issues related to things new in Java 8? I would appreciate someone shed some light on these series of issue and recommend the best practice.

Comment: Putting generics beside a class declaration declares wildcards. The interface should be something like `interface IA<A,B>`. Your `ClassA` should implement the interface with concrete types for the wildcards, and shouldn't have any generics of its own. `class ClassA implements IA<MyClass, String>`

Comment: @4castle: Right, I miss typed the interface in the post. So the interface is defined as interface IA<A,B> and my class is defined as class ClassA implements IA<MyClass, String>. Encountered issue with classes and interfaces like that.

Comment: Just want to clarify that the issues that I posted happens when class is defined as interface IA<A,B> and class ClassA implements IA<MyClass, String>. Any suggestions on the issue above?

Comment: Yes: 1-Add template parameters only for generic interfaces. In your case: `interface IA<A,B>{...}`. 2-Replace template parameters for concrete clasess only when referencing generic classes. In your case: `classA implements IA<MyClass, String>{...}`. And then `IA<MyClass, String> objectA=new ClassA(false)`.